# Не срабатывает меню, при нажатии на body

Tags: javascript, css, css3

есть тестовая страница [ссылка](http://test-workflow.florans.md/)

В мобильной версии при клике открывается меню, можно закрыть как при нажатии на крестик так и на body, но на body не срабатывает скрипт, какой то блок перекрывает
пробовал z-index c минусом ставить на header  срабатывает,  но уже не открывается меню 
                                                                                             Как решить, не могу догнать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. У вас событие установленно на блок `page-wrapper`,  а не на `body`.
2. `header` перекрывает блок `page-wrapper` из за чего не срабатывает событие.
3. Задайте блоку `page-wrapper` `z-index` больше чем у `header`, но меньше чем у `mobile-menu`.

Answer (score 1):

Так как надо закрыть меню (div#mobile-nav).
Если нажали где-то на экране но не на нём, то можем написать простой обработчик.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.id !== 'mobile-nav') {
    ... // тут функция для закрытия меню
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что у вас `header` на всю высоту блока.

**min-height: 100vh;**

Дайте нормальный размер вашему `header`-у чтобы он НЕ был над `body` и все будет работать